# React: как правильно вынести часть функции?

Tags: reactjs

**Вопрос решен!**

Делаю приложение по поиску картинок, у меня есть функция которая принимает API, и увеличивает на 1 страничку при нажатии кнопки Loadmore.

Но получилось так, что если я выношу из функции

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({  page: prevState.page + 1, }));
```

в отдельную функцию для кнопки loadMore, то все ломается.

Вот код: [LoadMore](https://github.com/Monerk98/goit-react-hw-03-image-finder/blob/main/src/components/App.js)

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

prevState находится в жизненном цикле componentDidUpdate, а вы пытаетесь вызвать его за пределами componentDidUpdate.
[Жизненный цикл реакт](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)